# Creating GORM dynamic query with optional paramters

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

I've been stuck on a GORM issue for about a full day now. I need to be able to filter a messages table on any of 4 things: sender, recipient, keyword, and date range. It also has to paginate. Filtering by sender and recipient is working, and so is pagination. So far this is the query that I have come up with, but it does not seem to work for date ranges or keywords.

Here is how I am selecting from MySQL

```
db.Preload("Thread").Where(query).Scopes(Paginate(r)).Find(&threadMessages)
```

I am creating the query like this:

```
var query map[string]interface{}
```

Then based on which parameters I am passed, I update the query like this by adding new key values to the map:

```
query = map[string]interface{}{"user_id": sender, "recipient_id": recipient}
```

For dates it does not seem to work if I try something like this:

```
query = map[string]interface{}{"created_at > ?": fromDate}
```

And for a LIKE condition is also does not seem to work:

```
query = map[string]interface{}{"contents LIKE ?": keyword}
```

The reason I chose this approach is that I could not seem to get optional inputs to work in .Where since it takes a string with positional parameters and null positional parameters seem to cause MySQL to return an empty array. Has anyone else dealt with a complicated GORM issue like this? Any help is appreciated at this point.

Answer (score 2):

Passing the `map[string]interface{}` into `Where()` only appears to work for **Equals** operations, or **IN** operations (if a slice is provided as the value instead).

One way to achieve what you want, is to construct a slice of `clause.Expression`, and append clauses to the slice when you need to. Then, you can simply pass in all of the clauses (using the `...` operator to pass in the whole slice) into `db.Clauses()`.

```golang
clauses := make([]clause.Expression, 0)

if mustFilterCreatedAt {
    clauses = append(clauses, clause.Gt{Column: "created_at", fromDate})
}

if mustFilterContents {
    clauses = append(clauses, clause.Like{Column: "contents", Value: keyword})
}

db.Preload("Thread").Clauses(clauses...).Scopes(Paginate(r)).Find(&threadMessages)
```

Note: If you're trying to search for content that contains `keyword`, then you should concatenate the wildcard `%` onto the ends of `keyword`, otherwise `LIKE` behaves essentially the same as `=`:

```golang
clause.Like{Column: "contents", Value: "%" + keyword + "%"}
```

Comment: Thanks. This does seem to accomplish what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

My final solution to this was to create dynamic Where clauses based on which query params were sent from the client like this:

```
    fields := []string{""}
    values := []interface{}{}
```

If, for example, there is a keyword param:

```
    fields = []string{"thread_messages.contents LIKE ?"}
    values = []interface{}{"%" + keyword + "%"}
```

And to use the dynamic clauses in the below query:

```
db.Preload("Thread", "agency_id = ?", agencyID).Preload("Thread.ThreadUsers", "agency_id = ?", agencyID).Joins("JOIN threads on thread_messages.thread_id = threads.id").Where("threads.agency_id = ?", agencyID).Where(strings.Join(fields, " AND "), values...).Scopes(PaginateMessages(r)).Find(&threadMessages)
```